# onDragOver for Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am having a hell of a time getting a MovieClip to detect whether another MovieClip is being dragged over it in ActionScript 3.0? Does anyone know of a good implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `DisplayObject.hitTestObject()`

```
movieClipOnStage.hitTestObject(movieClipYouAreDragging)
```

If you do this on a loop while you are dragging (using an `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, `Event.MOUSE_MOVE` or a `Timer` event) you should be able to get the result you are after.

Comment: I am actually using the on MOUSE_UP event for my implementation, but this is the right strategy.

Answer (score 0):

[DisplayObjectContainer.getObjectsUnderPoint()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint()) can do this for you.