# AS3 find movieClip under movieClip being dragged

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

I have a function dragging movieClips on the stage which pass over other movieClips which I'd like to identify somehow.

Is there a "built-in" way to do this in AS3?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [onDragOver for Actionscript 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338655/ondragover-for-actionscript-3-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`hitTestObject()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29).

> Evaluates the bounding box of the display object to see if it overlaps
>   or intersects with the bounding box of the obj display object.
>
> Parameters
>
> `obj:DisplayObject` — The display object to test against.
>
> Returns
>
> `Boolean` — `true` if the bounding boxes of the display objects intersect;
>   `false` if not.

Comment: Thanks Marty, there's a hitTestPoint() too that I found when looking at your suggestion, which will do just the job.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once, simplest way i found is to put OnMouseOver event listerners on your movieclips and OnMouseOut so you can know the mouse is over what. Keep a reference to the movieclip that triggers the event and nullify it if it triggers a OnMouseOut, so you know when your over a movieclip, put a OnMouseUp on the dragged movieclip so when its release you can look at which movieclip triggered OnMouseOver last and do what ever inventory you want.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I may try that in future.